# How can I make cells in a jquery-created table clickable?

Tags: jquery

I worked with PHP quite a lot and have always been a little afraid of javascript and jquery. But two weeks ago I made the jump to jquery and I must say I really love it :-) I made several working scripts, also thanks to info I found on stackoverflow. So thanks everyone :-)

But ... I spent many hours on this one issue I can not seem to solve... I will try to explain.

On an index.php file I create a table with php (drawn from a mysql database with the typical SELECT * FROM ...). Every cell gets a unique id (eg Cell_1_1 as first,...). With Jquery I have a script that detects a click on a cell, takes the id of the cell and places a text input field in there with the content of the cell. I then detect an 'onchange' event (like enter) to use ajax to call a php script that changes the value of this one cell in the actual Mysql database (with UPDATE ... WHERE id = cellid statement).

This all works fine and I am very happy with the power of jquery :-)

For another reason however I want to create the original table not with php but with jquery. This also works fine. If you compare it the outputted html it is identical to that of the php script. But for some reason the jquery script can not detect when I click on a cell (of the jquery table). It has no problem placing a text field in the cell when I bind the detect on an external div.

So jquery 'recognizes' the cell id's to change the cell. But not to detect onclick events.

Does anyone have any idea how this is possible?

Some parts of the code to clarify:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  makeclickable();
  // script1: build the table when clicked on a div with the name of the table
  $(".showtable_x").click(function() { 
    var idlastclick = $(this).attr("id"); //take tablename from click
    $.ajax({ //let php return an array with the titles and the content of the table                                   
      url: 'inc/api/api.php',
      data: '&table='+idlastclick,
      dataType: 'json',
      success: function(rows)        
      {
        var table = $('<table></table>');
        var numrow = rows.length; // take number of rows
        var numcol = rows[0].length; // number of cols
        for (i=0; i<numrow; i++){ // for every row
          var row = rows[i]; // take row from array
          var row2 = $('<tr></tr>'); //create html row
          for (j=0; j<numcol; j++){ // for every cell
            var cell = $('<td></td>').html(row[j]);//place content of array in cell
            var cellcounter = "cell_"+i+"_"+j; 
            cell.attr('id', cellcounter); // asign meaningfull id to the cell
            if (i==0) {
              var cell = cell.addClass("bgcolor1");
            } //the titles of the table
            row2.append(cell); // append the cell to the row
          }
          table.append(row2); // append the row to the table
        } // end for i
        $('#firstplaceholder').html(table);
      } // end function
    }); // end ajax;
  }); // end script 1
```

// script2: make sure cells are clickable and write to the database. (Works fine on a php created table)

```
  function makeclickable() {
    $('td').click( function() { // when click on cell
      if (!$("td.active")[0]){ // only execute when there is no other cell 'active'
        var idlastclick = $(this).attr("id"); // take id of the cell
        var content = $('#'+idlastclick).text(); // take the content of the cell
        $('#'+idlastclick).html("<input type='text' id='textie' value='' />").addClass("active"); 
        $('#textie').attr("value", content).focus();    
        // place a textfield, place the content of the cell, mark the cell as 'active', focus on it
        $('#textie').on("keyup change", function() { // on type, remember the new value
          var value = this.value; 
          $('#textie').on("change", function() { // on enter
            $("td.active").empty().removeClass("active").addClass("exiting"); // clear cell, remove 'active' status, mark it (by class) as the cell to be written in
            $("td.exiting").html(value); // place new value in cell 
            // call php script that writes the new value to the database
            $.ajax({                                      
              url: 'inc/api/api2.php',
              data: '&celid='+idlastclick+'&content='+value,
            }); 
          }); // end 'on enter' detection
        }); // end 'on key-stroke' detection
        $("td.exiting").removeClass("exiting"); // restore original class to cell
      } // end if
    });
  }
});
```

Comment: You don't need a fiddle for everything. Especially for something simple like that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You attach your onclick-handler to all `<td>` tags before you even create any.

Execute `makeclickable()` **after** you have created the table and it should work.

Comment: Thank you n.st! I tried this before I posted here (on different places in the code) but yett I tried again (directly after creating the table in html INSIDE the first script) and now it does work! :-) Also with the writing in the database ;-) 

Jeej!

Only problem I have left is that if I type quickly in the textfield and enter it does not always take the complete value and sometimes misses some letters at the end (in the database, not in the jquery variabele). 

By accident any thoughts on that?

Thanks to all who took the time to reply!!

Comment: @user2865764 They way you're currently doing it, your script will send an Ajax request after every single letter you type - which can cause excessive network traffic and probably also race conditions (leading to the problem you describe). It would be better to only send a request to the server if the user just pressed `Enter` or (if that's not an option) if the user hasn't pressed a key for a certain amount of time.

Comment: Thank you. Indeed I only want it to send on enter but I thought that is what I am doing. Doesn't the 'on change' only happens when entered (or clicked outside)? Sorry for my ignorance :(

Comment: @user2865764 Take a look at this minimal example of what your code does: http://jsfiddle.net/qfcRr/ You will notice that your *change* handler is called multiple times - which isn't surprising since you are **adding** (not replacing) a *change* handler every time the *keyup* handler is executed. Instead, you should only add the *change* handler once (and possibly ditch the *keyup* handler, since you can just as well access the value in the *change* handler): http://jsfiddle.net/uThKs/1/

Comment: Indeed, you are right. I understand now it was pointless to use the 'on change' inside the 'on keyup'. Only the 'on change' is cleaner, more logical and does the job. Thanks! everything works now! Also thanks for pointing me to to jsfiddle. First time I see it :).

Answer (score 1):

Use **[on()](http://api.jquery.com/on)** for event delegation like,

**Use**

```
$(document).on("keyup change",'#textie', function() {
```

**in place of**

```
$('#textie').on("keyup change", function() {
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer Rohan. I tried your suggestion but does not change the behaviour, sorry. Do you have other ideas? Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

Executing $(/**/).click(); will only attach to html elements, which already exists. For dynamically added elements, you have to choices.

1. Attach the event manually again (Check that you not double bind it to already existing elements)
2. Use event bubbling or delegation and catch the click event on a parent element, as example table via the .on() method. This is the preferred way.

Example:

```
$('#myTable').on('click', 'td', function () {/*your code goes here*/});
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer yan.kun. I did this: I did not have an id yet for the table itself. So I added that and replaced the first line of the second script with your line. I am soryy to say it still does not work. (I tried the same with the php created table and there it does work). Any ideas? (I must say I did not understand the first choice though)

Comment: You need attach the event handler to your first placeholder element, as your table is also dynamically created.

Answer (score 0):

You have to delegate the click event to the parent container (which is not dynamically added) in your `makeclickable()` function like that :

```
$('table').on('click', 'td', function () {
    ...
}
```

See JQuery doc : [.on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/)

Hope I helped you !

Comment: Thanks for your answer risk.  I tried your suggestion (similar to the suggestion of yan kun) but does not change the behaviour, sorry. Do you have other ideas? Thanks again!

Comment: Your table is also dynamically appended... you can use `$(document).on('click', 'td', ... `

Answer (score 0):

you use [**on()**](http://api.jquery.com/on/) is actually created this for that problem..for the element that created ***"on the fly"***..